# Find how many solutions the equation $x^3\equiv 5 \pmod {143}$ has.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

> Find how many solutions the following equation has:
> $x^3\equiv 5 \pmod {143}$

Using Euler's criterion I found that the equation $x^3\equiv 5 \pmod {11}$  has one solution, and $x^3\equiv 5 \pmod {13}$ has 3 solutions.
How can I conclude from that how many solutions the original equation has? I thought maybe to use the CRT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have $m$ solutions to $f(x)\equiv0\bmod p$ and $n$ to $f(x)\equiv0\bmod q$, every pair of solutions to the sub-congruences combines by the CRT into a distinct solution modulo $pq$, so there are $mn$ solutions to the mod-$pq$ congruence.

Thus, in your case, there are $3×1=3$ solutions.

Comment: can you explain why -"every pair of solutions to the sub-congruences combines by the CRT into a distinct solution modulo pq"?

Comment: @Emma Because $\mathbb Z_{pq}\cong\mathbb Z_p×\mathbb Z_q$ - the two spaces (mod $pq$) and (mod $p$, mod $q$) are isomorphic.

Comment: @Emma Because that is what the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) says. A set of remainders from divisions of $n$ by some coprime numbers *uniquely determines* the remainder of the division by $n$ by the product of those numbers.